# Can languages that are not closed against the Kleene star be regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I've been working on finding a regular expression for the following language for quite some time now ($\Sigma =\text{{0, 1}}$):

> $
> \text{L = {w | the difference between the number of 0's and 1's in each prefix of the word is less than or equal to 1}}$

I haven't been able to find an expression for this particular language so far, so I was wondering if the language is regular at all.

The following came to mind, but I'm pretty dubious about its validity :

> Since $010$ belongs to said language, and by concatenation $010010$ does not, it would follow that this language isn't closed under Kleene star, hence it's not regular.

Am I wrong? If so, could you help with finding the solution to this problem?

Regarding the meaning of prefix in this context, the prefixes of the string $abcd$ are $\text{{$abcd, abc, ab, a$}}$.

Comment: Don't confuse "the set of regular languages REG is closed against Kleene star" with "every regular language is closed against Kleene star".

Comment: You might be interested in this question: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4254/a-special-class-of-languages-circular-languages-is-it-known/12451#12451.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your argument is not correct.

The "hence it's not regular" doesn't follow.  Not every regular language is closed under Kleene star.  Some regular languages aren't closed under Kleene star.  I think you've misunderstood the closure property: the closure property states "If $L$ is regular, then $L^*$ is regular".  Note that you can still have a regular language where $L \ne L^*$.

To learn how to solve this question correctly, you may want to check out our [reference questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/599/).  See especially [How to prove a language is regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755), [Show whether the language with almost as many 0 as 1 in every prefix is regular](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/33257/755), [Language where every prefix has almost equal a's and b's](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19073/755).

Comment: Easy example: all finite languages are regular, but none of them are closed against the Kleene star. (As a matter of fact, take *any* language closed against KS, remove a single, well-chosen string, and you end up with a language of the same complexity (for most classes, that is) that is not closes against KS.)

Answer (score 3):

The language $L'=\{1\}$ is not closed under the Kleene's star (e.g. $11\not\in L'$), but is regular (use a FSA with two states).

The closure property states that when $L''$ is regular, then $L''^*$ (which is another language) must be regular as well. It does not imply $L''^* = L''$.

For your language $L$, try writing a decider in your own favorite programming language. If it turns out that the decider's variables only assume finitely many values, you can convert that into a FSA, proving $L$ regular.